# CakePHP / jQuery / JsHelper - AJAX form with elements in multiple table cells or divs

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am using the JsHelper to submit a form. But, when I try to submit the form when the form is encapsulated in a table for example, the submission goes ahead, but submits without the form data. I suspect it has to do with the jQuery function .closest('form') which the JsHelper uses when doing the AJAX submission to collect the data I presume. Does .closest() get confused when the form resides in multiple DOM elements? A simple example of my problem looks like:

```
<table><tr>
  <?php echo $this->Form->create(); ?>
  <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('item'); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $this->Js->submit('Send', array('update' => '#a-div')); ?></td>
  <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
</tr></table>
```

The above would make the AJAX submission but doesn't attach the ['Model']['item'] to the submission. Is there anyway to mitigate the problem, that is, still encapsulating the form in a few div's or table cells whilst still sending the relevant data correctly? I am trying to make the form look nice, so I want to use multiple DOM elements to format the form.

Comment: can you explain more simple?..i can't understand...:)

Comment: Ok, inside CakePHP, is it possible to get .closest() to grab the data in the same form but which resides in another DOM element (like the above)? (Whilst still using the JsHelper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there are no answers, I would now say the best way to do this is to do a manual AJAX submission instead of relying on the JsHelper. As far as I know, there are no CakePHP solutions.